# Add filename as a column in .txt file and concatenate into a single file

Tags: bash, unix

I have 28 directories with names as such as such:

```
_.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet
_.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_Endothelia_GeneSet
_.LD_RESULTS_Polydendrocytes_Endothelia_GeneSet
_.LD_RESULTS_Microglia.x_Microglia.y_GeneSet
_.LD_RESULTS_Endothelia_Neurons_GeneSet
```

They all contain different `.txt` files (around 20 per directory).

```
_.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet_ADHD.cell_type_results.txt               _.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet_Height.cell_type_results.txt
_.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet_ALS.cell_type_results.txt                _.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet_Insomnia.cell_type_results.txt
_.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet_Alzheimers.cell_type_results.txt
```

I am trying to add these filenames as a column to the text files, and concatenate them all into a single file and call it foldername_results.txt

I started with this, which works at concatenating all .txt files into a single file called all_results.txt, across all directories.

```
for d in *; do
  [[ -d "$d" ]] && cd "$d" || continue
  awk '{print $0,FILENAME}' *.txt > all_results.txt
  cd -
done
```

I only want to slightly modify this so that `all_results.txt` includes the directory name as well. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
...
awk -v dir="$PWD" '{print $0,dir,FILENAME}' ...
...
```

Comment: So the command works when I am in the directory. Any ideas how to get it working in the context of the loop itself?

Comment: Just replace the awk script with this, it will work in the loop as well.  Perhaps I didn't understand the question.

Comment: It doesn't work in the loop (it seems to go into the first directory and never leave) whereas my awk script does.

Comment: it will work, you go back with `cd -`.  You just need to pass the directory name to `awk` to print.  I didn't change anything else in your script.  `PWD` will have the current directory name.  Of course you can do the same without actually changing directories but that's completely changing your script.  Note that your `awk` script just prints the filename, it doesn't change directories.  Your `bash` script does the rest.